# How to create new ServerSocket C#

Tags: c#, server, system.net, system.net.sockets

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace PowerCarsMobileServer
{
    class Server
    {
        public static int Port { get; private set; }
        private static TcpListener tcpListener;
        public static ServerSocket serverSocket; //problem is here
        public static void Start(int _port)
        {
            Port = _port;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
            InitializeServerData();
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"Server started on {Port}.");
        }
    }
}
```

When creating a global port, I ran into the problem of not supporting "ServerSocket". Older articles use ServerSocket but I don't understand the problem comparing my code with theirs.

How can I fix it?

I tried to connect different references, but it doesn't work or I didn't find a good one

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the older article you are referring to?

Comment: `ServerSocket` isn't a standard .NET BCL class. Gotta rewrite wherever you have it from.

Comment: How else can you solve the problem of server globalization? 
I need to make sure that the client can connect from different IP addresses, and not just localhost.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837325/android-serversocket-not-sending-data-to-client-client-c-server-java - the code presented here uses ServerSocket

Comment: @PavelSheludko: the link you refer to is Android/Java SDK and not C#/.NET. You have already solved your problem by listening on `IPAddress.Any`.

Comment: @YK1: At the moment, a successful connection is carried out only using the local host (127.0.0.1). I think that you can solve the problem by opening the port I need, but I don’t know how to do it (Connection from the client side will be done from android and ios devices)

Comment: @PavelSheludko: likely because windows firewall may be blocking remote connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using .Net and ServerSocket is an Android class.

To setup a server socket TCP connection in .Net:

```
    OptionalStateObject state = new OptionalStateObject();
    Socket newSocket = null;
    //A state object should be included and is required for all subsequent  
    //receives on the new socket. e.g. state.byteArray = new 
    //byte[BUFFER_SIZE];      
    Socket ServerTcpSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Task.Run(() => 
     {
         ServerTcpSocket.Listen(100);
         while(!cancel)
         {
             ServerTcpSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        state);
          }
     });
```

And in the AcceptCallback delegate:

```
    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            newSocket = ServerTcpSocket.EndAccept(ar);
            state = (OptionalStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {   }
     }
```

And the connection is established on newSocket where you can start receiving:

```
    Task.Run(() => //replace with extension method
    {
        state.byteArray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        newSocket.BeginReceive(state.byteArray, 0,
             BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, 
             new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    });
```

The data can then be accessed from the state.byteArray in the ReceiveCallback delegate.

> "How else can you solve the problem of server globalization? I need to
> make sure that the client can connect from different IP addresses, and
> not just localhost."

If the server app is listening in some remote location where the ip address is known (i.e. for all websites and server-side services on Azure or AWS) all external clients from any location on the internet will be able to initiate a connection for two-way communications.

Comment: Everything you said is generally correct, however it would be better not to access `ar` after calling `EndAccept`, since that function frees any resources held by `ar`.